# Evaluating a probability density function using polar coordinates

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm looking at the following probability density function:

$$\sqrt{5+x^2+y^2}$$ where $$ 1 \le x^2+y^2 \le 4 $$

I'm trying to find the $P(0<X<3Y)$ and to do this I've converted this to polar coordinates and am trying to take the integral to get the probability: $$ \int\int \sqrt{1+r^2}*r*drd\theta $$ I'm really unsure how to assign the bounds for this, and if anyone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it

Comment: The PDF haven't normalized yet.

Comment: I have to suspect that given circular symmetry, this is going to be something like $\dfrac{\tan^{-1}(3)}{2 \pi} \approx 0.199$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(0<X<3Y)=P(0<\frac{X}{3}<Y)=\int_{\mathbb{R^2}}{1_{\{0<\frac{x}{3}<y\}}1_{\{1<x^2+y^2\leq4\}}}\sqrt{5+x^2+y^2}dxdy$

Geometrically, $D=\{1<x^2+y^2\leq 4\}$ is the disc of radian 2 to which we substract the disc of radian 1. In other words,in polar coordinates $D=\{r\in]1,2], \theta\in]0,2\pi]\}$

Then we draw the straight line $x->\frac{x}{3}$, we take all elements above the straight line. Because it passes by $(0,0)$, it is a diameter, and  the angle of  eligible surface in $D$ is $\pi$.
Finally , you have to integrate on $$C=\{r\in]1,2], \theta\in]\theta_0,\theta_0+2\pi]\}$$, where $\theta_0=arctan(\frac{1}{3})$

Therefore,$P(0<X<3Y)=\int_{C}{r\sqrt{5+r^2}drd\theta}$

Comment: $$\theta_0+\pi$$